# jquery current timestamp minus one day (repeats for 30 days)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made this function tonight to create random data for a demo chart page.  I want to create random data for each day for the last 30 days.

My thought process was to get the current UTC timestamp and then subtract `(count++ * 3600000)` for each day of data.  Everything works fine except my timestamp never changes so every day of data is for the current day.  Ideas?

```
//current timestamp
var curr_date = $.now();

//random data generator up to 300
function randomData(label, color) {

    //counter
    var count = 0;

    //rand value
    function randValue() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 300);
    }

    series = [
        {label: label, color: color,
        data: [
            [curr_date - (count * 3600000), randValue()],
            [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
            [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
            [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
            [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
            [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
            [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
            [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
            [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
            [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
            [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
            [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
            [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
            [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
            [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
            [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
            [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
            [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
            [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
            [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
            [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
            [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
            [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
            [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
            [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
            [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
            [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
            [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
            [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
            [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()]
        ]}
    ];

    return series;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My brain must be fried - 86400000 is the value of one day in js.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a work around for this here: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arsbm/)

```
//current timestamp
var curr_date = $.now();

//random data generator up to 300
function randomData(label, color) {

    //counter
    var count = 0;

    //rand value
    function randValue() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 300);
    }

//this.test=[count,count++,count++];

this.series = [
    {label: label, color: color,
    data: [
        [curr_date - (count * 3600000), randValue()],
        [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
        [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
        [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
        [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
        [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
        [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
        [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
        [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
        [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
        [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
        [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
        [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
        [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
        [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
        [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
        [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
        [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
        [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
        [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
        [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
        [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
        [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
        [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
        [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
        [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
        [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
        [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
        [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()],
        [curr_date - (count++ * 3600000), randValue()]
    ]}
];
}

var randomData=new randomData('label','color');
console.log(randomData.series);
```